# Is it correct to assign int64_t or int32_t to ptrdiff_t?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, 32-bit

Whilst working on porting a c++ cross platform (Windows & Linux) 32 bit code to accommodate 64 bit environments I had the following question:

On a 32 bit system is it functionally correct to assign a value from an int32_t type to a ptrdiff_t type?

On a 64 bit system is it functionally correct to assign a value from an int64_t type to a ptrdiff_t type?

Out of interest: On a 64 bit system is it functionally correct to assign a value from an int32_t type to a ptrdiff_t type?

Context: the signed ptrdiff_t value is used in some iterator arithmetic and could possibly take on a negative value as subtraction is used in the iterator arithmetic logic.

Comment: [Reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) says it's implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

`ptrdiff_t` is in practice 32 bits on a 32-bit system, and 64 bits on a 64-bit system. It <sup>(1)</sup>can't be less. On a 16-bit system it has to be at least 17 (yes, that's not a typo) bits.

Since you ask, it's likely that some who maintain the code is unsure about this.

For them, just `static_assert` the sizes requirements, e.g. `static_assert( sizeof(ptrdiff_t) >= sizeof(int), "")`.

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> `ptrdiff_t` has to be sufficient to represent the pointer difference of any two arbitrary pointers to `char` in a contiguous array, so it must support the largest possible array of bytes.</sup>